# Can Javascript be used to counter SSL/TLS vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, ssl

To my great horror, I recently discovered that the SSL/TLS protocol that I until then had considered a safe choice for ensuring my users' integrity, in fact suffers from several vulnerabilities, with exploits available ([CAs in 2009](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2009/07/kaminsky/), [renegotiation exploit in 2009](http://www.pcworld.com/article/182720/security_pro_says_new_ssl_attack_can_hit_many_sites.html) and [BEAST in 2011](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/beast_exploits_paypal_ssl/)). Thus, it seems that several other minor vulnerabilities exist.

So the great question remains, what to do? As I have understood, the last two exploits I linked to above requires a fair amount of previously known information and then some guessing (BEAST) or can only partly exploit my "secured" connection, as it cannot actually decrypt the sent data (renegotiation). However, the methods still seems very, very threatening, and I doubt it'll be long before hackers have added the exploits to their arsenals.

As an obvious countermeasure, I thought of adding an additional layer of encryption with Javascript to the extra sensitive parts of the webapps I take care of. I know a few good encryption libraries is coming up out there, so the encryption itself is not the issue. The issue, however, is that I've also read [this fine article about Javascript as a cryptographic security measure](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/), and it's criticism of the method has made me wondering if additional security using Javascript is possible/sensible at all.

The thing is, that I think perhaps Javascript encryption anyhow *could* make things more secure, as at least the last two I linked to are man-in-the-middle attacks, so perhaps the extra encryption would ruin their attack (and I *don't know* the SSL/TLS protocol well at all).

Do you think adding extra encryption with Javascript (to secured, controlled environments) would eliminate these threats?

**EDIT:**

I think the 3 answers so far has misunderstood me a bit. I know very well that a *fully* breached SSL/TLS connection renders any further Javascript encryption useless (as you point out - the Javascript itself would be compromised and presumeably altered). *However*, neither of the exploits I mentioned does - as I understand it - allow an attacker to fully compromise the connection immediately, especially not the renegotiation exploit. The question is more about if anyone who knows SSL/TLS well and the cryptocraphic difficulties of Javascript could shed some light on the issue of whether Javascript encryption could protect against these two specific exploits?

Still though, the conclusion I'm coming to is that it won't add security. If anything because I've become doubtful that Javascript by itself is a language capable of doing cryptography properly (after reading [a little more about cryptography best practices](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology)), primarily because of its lack of a secure random number generator. And then all the other fine reasons written about in the answers puts the final nail in the coffin to *that* idea.

Comment: In my opinion, anything that is run on the client machine. (I.E. Javascript) cannot be used as a good means to protect data. I did not post it as an answer however, because it is just that - my opinion.

Comment: @DeviantSeev: I totally agree with you in any other case, but I think that when it's only a matter of encrypting some data, and then send it to the server for it to try to unencrypt it and then validate it as it must do with any data, the kind of integrity I believe you think about is not the issue.

Comment: See the problem is that when a user has access to something, such as a script that you're using for encryption then you're asking for trouble. Odds are that nobody will modify this script to do anything harmful but you're putting yourself out there. Someone will come along and question why you're encrypting data using code which can be easily modified by the client. That's one of the points listed in that link that you provided in your question. My suggestion - don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before thinking of adding an additional layer of encryption using JavaScript because SSL/TLS is allegedly broken, you should really understand what the issues you've mentioned about SSL/TLS really are. The information published in the general press (the links you've posted) can be a be simplified, misleading or sensationalistic.

### Problems with certificates

This is not a vulnerability of SSL/TLS in itself, although it is important of course. Whatever new system you design will have to rely on an infrastructure to identify the remote party. The are a number of models for this (based on public key cryptography), mainly PKIs (a la X.509, see [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)) and Web-of-Trust (a la PGP).

These problems fall into sub-categories:

- The host name for which the certificate has been issued is not checked properly (example with `\0` that would pass for another host): that's an implementation bug. As regrettable as it is, bugs are implemented regularly, sometimes in security-related code indeed. The design of SSL/TLS is not to blame here. The implementation of the host name verification is. (See [RFC 2818 section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) for HTTPS or [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125).) This can be solved by fixing the bugs in the library/browser and upgrading to a fixed version. Failure to implement specifications properly will happen once in a while with any protocol, SSL/TLS or not. (Granted, the "clarity" of ASN.1 structures that make X.509 certificates doesn't help...)
- The host name might not be displayed clearly in the browser. GUIs are an area that can be improved, but it seems difficult to educate users accordingly too. Attempts have been made, for example, to push for using Extended Validation certificates (green bar), but this may also have created some additional confusion (not without some clever marketing from those who benefit financially the most from EV certs).
- CAs can sometimes make mistake when issuing a certificate (or be compromised). Perhaps those CA certificates shouldn't be in your browser in the first place.

The problems are not purely technical here. It's more about how, as a human, you can check whether you want to trust the piece of information put in front of you (i.e. whether you believe the certificate is genuine and is that of the server you want to talk to).

I believe this problem doesn't have a perfect solution. Trust is a very hard thing to model. This sort of situation could happen in any situation, not necessarily related with SSL/TLS or internet. (How many of your friends's passports have you seen to check their names? Are they all genuine? Are you sure
they haven't been issued after the authorities were given some false information?)

The implementations may not be perfect, and browser developers can work to fix bugs and improve GUIs. However, I don't think any JavaScript add-on will fix any of this: you'll still need a similar way to identify the remote party. There are browser add-ons that can partly help (e.g. by comparing to other cached copies of the certificate), but ultimately, it's the user's responsibility to choose whether or not to trust the identity of the server.

(The other weakness with this is that some developers don't seem to want to understand that area too much: see the number of questions on SO asking how to disable certificate verification, to get rid of the warning messages. It's a human problem too, if people want not to see the warning message.)

### Renegotiation exploit (CVE-2009-3555) and BEAST

The renegotiation exploit was a protocol bug indeed, but this was fixed in [RFC 5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746). (It was argued at the time that it wasn't purely an SSL/TLS bug, but that it was also an issue with how SSL/TLS interacts with the application protocol which it secures. It's a problem that might have been averted if the HTTP stacks had been able to be notified of an SSL/TLS renegotiation, but this was a grey area and HTTP servers weren't really designed for this anyway: too late and/or too big a task.) The problems regarding the fix have to do with deployment. It's quite difficult to upgrade everyone at the same time. Encouraging people to upgrade to newer versions of TLS (and ditch SSL, actually) would help here.

BEAST is a problem (quite specific to browsers), but this can be fixed by a better configuration of the SSL/TLS stack, or by upgrading to more recent versions of SSL/TLS, again.

It seems here that SSL/TLS is victim of stagnation when it comes to version upgrades. This is of course more problematic than other pieces of software because the remote party (which may be an online customer you have never met) would often have to upgrade their version of SSL/TLS too.
I would say that, while it's important (often for business purposes) not to exclude a number of users who can't or won't update their browser/OS, there comes a point where servers need to upgrade anyway.
Again, this is unfortunately not specific to SSL/TLS. Any sort of web development that needs to support IE6 will have similar problems (and [it should be killed off...](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)).

Again, I doubt very strongly that a JavaScript-based solution won't suffer from similar problems (in particular, browser compatibility and version issues).

Comment: This was just the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you! :-) Once again, the conclusion must be that one cannot hope to add security to a sensible data transfer using Javascript. But I'm very glad for the insight, much appreciated :-)

Comment: If you're really interested in SSL/TLS, [Eric Rescorla's book](http://www.amazon.com/SSL-TLS-Designing-Building-Systems/dp/0201615983/) is really good. (I think there might be more recent books on the subject, though, with newer versions of TLS and extensions.)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the JS crypto would be better than SSL/TLS, even with the aforementioned vulnerabilities. If you are good enough/motivated enough to break SSL, then some JS crypto won't be an issue - particularly with the numerous issues. Proper random numbers and ensuring correct delivery being the main ones.

On the other hand, adding more encryption might be fairly trivial, and might make you feel better.

I would carefully consider what the risks are for your users, then work towards mitigating those first (though I'm sure you have already).

Comment: Well, the risks that I'm afraid of on behalf of my users in this case is not the obvious server-attacks (like XSS), as I'm of course taking measures against those. The issues lies with the security to protect my users' datas' integrity while on the way and which I thought to be well in place - SSL/TLS. I'm however fairly worried to add extra encryption if it doesn't provide added security, as it would surely make the user experience suffer.

Comment: And about the core issue - can Javascript do the job - I understand that you don't think JS crypto would render the two specific exploits mentioned useless?

Comment: Without proper random numbers and a guaranteed way to send the script without modification, JS crypto just makes you feel better, and does provide some security, but it's not 'secure' in all senses of the word. In this case you are worried about the secure transport, so you want to send some code over that insecure channel to make it more secure. If you feel you can't trust the connection, there is nothing to add to that that will make it more secure. On the other hand, is SSL really that insecure? I'd keep it as SSL/TLS and make sure you are as uptodate as possible there.

Comment: Putting in encryption in JS is like relying on your sparkly magic tiger-repellent alice band. Not only does it _not work in any useful way_, it distracts from taking steps that actually matter.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the article criticizing JavaScript crypto serious. JavaScript will not make your application any more secure. And it will not render the mentioned exploits useless.

If an attacker is able to manipulate the connection through SSL/TLS, he will also be able to manipulate the JavaScript source files.

In a real world example - you are using JavaScript to hash user passwords on the client-side so they are not sent as plaintext over the line (people actually do this) - an attacker could just replace the sha1 method by `function sha1(pwd) { return pwd; }` and then read the password on the connection he is sniffing.

Also on this topic: You have to learn that you [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210). Don't download a random encryption algorithm implemented in JavaScript and use it to some things - it's not going to be secure, because you do not know what you are doing.

I hope my example is understandable. It should also apply to more complex scenarios (like Public-key cryptography, etc.).

**Edit** - Response to your edit:

Whether or not an additional layer of JavaScript cryptography will fix these bugs or not is hard to figure out.

But my point was, if you use that JavaScript AES library, you will be kind of inventing your own cryptographic protocol - which is bad. Also see Bruno's answer; this really is not a thing you can fix, or be worried about. And even if you could, your approach of doing it in JavaScript would probably still fail at some point (as you figured out yourself).

Comment: Oh no, I'm not going to roll my own crypto :-). I thought of downloading a good implementation of, say, the AES algorithm like SJCL - http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Comment: About the connection manipulation, please read my edit to the question. I am fully aware of the problems you mention, you see, I just think I've not been clear enough in my explanation :-). And thank you, btw, your answer is much appreciated.